# reshaping 3 columns into matrix

Tags: r, matrix, reshape2

I have 3 columns of data that I would like to reshape into a matrix where the columns are `created_at` and rows are `citibike_station_id`

```
head(sample)
  available_bike_count          created_at citibike_station_id
1                   21 2015-10-08 00:00:00                  72
2                    7 2015-10-08 20:10:00                  72
3                   18 2015-10-08 06:50:00                  72
4                   19 2015-10-08 10:10:00                  72
5                   18 2015-10-08 02:30:00                  72
6                   17 2015-10-08 05:00:00                  72
> dim(sample)
[1] 69511     3
```

Therefore, I have to group by `created_at` and by `citibike_station_id`

```
> length(unique(sample$created_at))
[1] 145

> length(unique(sample$citibike_station_id))
[1] 482
```

`created_at` represents a 10-minute time intervals - there should be 145 columns as there are 145 unique time intervals (representing one day of data) ; and there should be 482 rows as there are 482 unique values of `citibike_station_id`.

This is an example of what the data should look like in the end - however, in this example the column names are from a different day and year.

```
head(data[1:6])
  station_id X2014.08.18.20.00.00 X2014.08.18.20.10.00 X2014.08.18.20.20.00
1          1                    1                    0                    0
2          2                   18                   18                   19
3          3                    5                    4                    4
4          4                   21                   20                   20
5          5                    9                   10                    8
6          6                    9                    9                    9
  X2014.08.18.20.30.00 X2014.08.18.20.40.00
1                    2                    1
2                   18                   18
3                    4                    4
4                   21                   22
5                    5                    7
6                    9                    9
```

how would one do this with `dplyr` and `tidyr` ?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

matrix <-  sample  %>% 
  group_by(created_at, citibike_station_id)%>%
  spread(citibike_station_id, created_at)
```

however this does not work.  Would the `reshape2` package provide a better solution?

Comment: You could try the `melt` function from `reshape2` using the argument `id.vars = c('created at','citibike_station_id')` Not sure if it will be what you want though.

Comment: yes, and then use `acast` ?